# Convert str command output to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I get an output of a command like below in str:

```
Group Name: STI              IP: v4          Comment:
Group Items:  2                Type: User-defined
Members: "vm-1" "vm-2"
```

I want to be able to convert it into a dictionary so that I get a key-value pair like below:

```
{"Group Name": "STI", "IP": "v4", "Comment": "", "Group Items": "2", "Type": "User-defined", "Members": '"vm-1" "vm-2"'}
```

How to achieve the same?

The output got squeezed when I pasted it here, so attaching snippet of the same: [image]

Comment: What does the actual string look like? `Group Name: STI IP: v4 Comment: Group Items: 2 `?  So space separated?

Comment: @PyPingu- it looks exactly like the screenshot with same amount of spaces as shown

Answer (score 0):

If the output has always the same format, I guess you best bet is to parse the text like this:

```
>>> text = '''Group Name: STI              IP: v4          Comment:
... Group Items:  2                Type: User-defined
... Members: "vm-1" "vm-2"'''
>>> text = text.split("\n")
>>> {"Group Name": text[0][12:29], "IP": text[0][33:45], "Comment": text[0][54:], "Group Items": text[1][13:30], "Type": text[1][37:], "Members": text[2][9:]}
{'Group Name': 'STI              ', 'IP': 'v4          ', 'Comment': '', 'Group Items': ' 2               ', 'Type': 'User-defined', 'Members': '"vm-1" "vm-2"'}
```

You split the text into lines, and then take the slices you need.

If the output may have a different format, that would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @jferad- Thanks for your efforts